# flower identification using cnn keras on windows 10

Tags: keras

on my project related to machine learning,flower identification using CNN keras..showing following errors
ERRORS :

```
 Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py:846: RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_acc` which is not available. Available metrics are: val_loss,val_accuracy,loss,accuracy
  (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
```

on the  code:

```
#using Grid Search and Early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', verbose=2, patience=25)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('./best_model_1.h5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=2, save_best_only=True)

Hyp_Model_1 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=Revised_1_fn)
#You need to pick the right hyper-parameters for your training (try with different ones)

learn_rate = [0.01]
batch_size = [32,75,100]
epochs = [5]

param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, learn_rate = learn_rate)
randSearch_1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = Hyp_Model_1, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5)

new_grid_1 = randSearch_1.fit(X_train,y_train, validation_data = (X_val, y_val), verbose=2,callbacks=[es,mc])
```

Comment: The error message clearly guides you about what the exact problem is and what to change in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the error message, Keras does not recognize `val_acc` as a metric; you will need to type in `val_accuracy` as listed in the available options.